# Apple Itms-services:// Problems in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ios, ipad, plist

I have a problem. In my asp.net application I store the *.plist and *.ipa files in a sql database. 
Over a webcontroll I access them (http://domain/asppage/dist/filecontroller.aspx?plistId=2).
So on computer it works perfect.
If I try to download over iPad it doesn't work, also if I add the "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=" thing. 
But I can download over ipad if I directly point an uploaded *.plist file.

So isn't it possible to download a database stored plist file over the link itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://foo/dist/FileController.aspx?plistName=Approvaltest" from the iPad?

Comment: it's solved, watch below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem.

If you want to use parameters in your link together with itms-services, please encode your chars. So for the "?" (questionmark) use %3F and for the "=" (equal) use %3D.